# SQL Server 2014 Consolidate Tables avoiding duplicates

Tags: sql-server

I have 36 `Sales` tables each referred to one store:

```
st1.dbo.Sales  
st2.dbo.Sales  
...  
st35.dbo.Sales  
st36.dbo.Sales
```

Each record has the following key columns:

```
UserName, PostalCode, Location, Country, InvoiceAmount, ItemsCount, StoreID
```

Here is [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0afee)

I need to copy into `Customers` table all Username (and their details) that are not already present into `Customers`

in case of duplicated it is required to use the fields of record where `InvoiceAmount` is MAX

I tried to build a query but looks too complicated and it is also wrong because in `CROSS APPLY` should consider the full list of `Sales` Tables

```
INSERT INTO Customers (.....)
    SELECT distinct 
        d.UserName, 
        w.postalCode, 
        w.location, 
        W.country,  
        max(w.invoiceamount) invoiceamount, 
        max(w.itemscount) itemscount,
        w.storeID
    FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM st1.dbo.Sales
         UNION              
         SELECT * FROM st2.dbo.Sales
         UNION
         ...
         SELECT * FROM st36.dbo.Sales) d
    LEFT JOIN 
        G.dbo.Customers s ON d.Username = s.UserName
    CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP (1) * 
         FROM s.dbo.[Sales]  
         WHERE d.Username=w.Username
         ORDER BY InvoiceAmount DESC) w
    WHERE 
        s.UserName IS NULL
        AND d.username IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        d.UserName, w.postalCode, w.location,    
        w.country, w.storeID
```

Can somebody please give some hints?

Comment: What is the schema of `customers` and particularly PK / Unique Key ? I suspect username + storeID. What invoiceamount and itemcount do in `customers`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a basic SQL query, I'd create a row_number in the inner subquery and then join to customers and then isolated the max invoice number for each customer not in the customer table.

```
INSERT INTO Customers (.....)
    SELECT w.UserName, 
        w.postalCode, 
        w.location, 
        w.country,  
        w.invoiceamount, 
        w.itemscount,
        w.storeID
    FROM (select d.*,
              row_number() over(partition by d.Username order by d.invoiceamount desc) rownumber 
          from  (SELECT * 
                 FROM st1.dbo.Sales
                 UNION              
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM st2.dbo.Sales
                 UNION
                 ...
                 SELECT * 
                 FROM st36.dbo.Sales
                ) d 
           LEFT JOIN G.dbo.Customers s 
               ON d.Username = s.UserName
           WHERE s.UserName IS NULL
               AND d.username IS NOT NULL
         ) w
    where w.rownumber = 1
```

Comment: you don't need `group by` here.

Comment: Wow! works great!.. bad thing is that this means I have really a lot to learn :-(

Answer (score 0):

Using your fiddle this will select distinct usernames rows with max invoiceamount

```
with d as(
  SELECT * FROM Sales
  UNION              
  SELECT * FROM Sales2
)
select *
from ( select *, 
      rn = row_number() over(partition by Username order by invoiceamount desc)
      from d) dd
where rn=1;
```

Comment: Thanks Serg, I can suppose row_number() was the solution, but I was too far from understanding

Answer (score 0):

step 1 - use cte .

```
                select  username , invoiceamount ,itemscount from Sales
          UNION all
               select  user name , invoiceamount ,itemscount from Sales
```

.....

...

step 2

next cte use group by and get max invoiceamount ,itemscount for user of last result set.

```
         ,cte2 as (

      select  user name , max (invoiceamount) as invoiceamount  ,max(itemscount) as itemscount  from  cte)
```

step3

use left join with user table and find missing record and itemscount invoiceamount